# Classifier for time based data to binary label

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have access to a dataframe of 100 persons and how they performed on a certain motion test. This frame contains about 25,000 rows per person since the performance of this person is kept track of (approximately) each centisecond (10^-2). We want to use this data to predict a binary y-label, that is to say, if someone has a motor problem or not.

Trained neural networks on mean's and variances of certain columns per person classified `+-72%` of the data correctly. 
Naive bayes classifier on mean's and variances of certain columns per person classified `+-80%` correctly.

Now since this is time based data, 'performance on this test through time', we were suggested to use Recurrent Neural Networks. I've looked into this and I find that this is mostly used to predict future events, i.e. the events happening in the next centiseconds.

Question is, is it in general feasible to use RNN's on (in a way time-based) data like this to predict a binary label? If not, what is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it definitely is feasible and also very common. Search for any document classification tasks (e.g. sentiment) for examples of this kind of tasks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am going to read into this one:  https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-on-sentiment-analysis-with-rnn-9e100627c02e.

Comment: I tried to, however the accuracy I got was around 50%. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54290619/recurrent-neural-network-binary-classification Do you have a suggestion maybe?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21987709)

Comment: @PhilippKief quoting from the OP: "Question is, is it in general feasible to use RNN's on (in a way time-based) data like this to predict a binary label?" my answer is "Yes it definitely is feasible and also very common". It is neither a critique or a request for clarifications, it is simply a direct answer. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @BlackBear you could've added more details to your answer than just saying "Yes it's feasible".